# library(WGCNA) Error in loadNamespace

Tags: r

I reinstalled RSTUDIO & R from scratch.
What package is "訴mpute"? it is not compute.es

Also, if anyone knows how to get rid of the KANJI/Chinese character, please let me know;
already removed all other languages leaving only English & rebooted.

perhaps no 'impute' for 3.0.3?

Warning in install.packages :
package 訴mpute・is not available (for R version 3.0.3)

thanks

## -------------------------------------------------------------

(R) library(WGCNA)
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) :
there is no package called 訴mpute・Error: package or namespace load failed for 糎GCNA・
(R) sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  splines   grid      datasets  grDevices stats     graphics  tcltk     utils
[10] methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] compute.es_0.2-3      mlbench_2.1-1         randomGLM_1.02-1      doParallel_1.0.8
[5] iterators_1.0.6       MASS_7.3-29           Hmisc_3.14-3          Formula_1.1-1
[9] survival_2.37-7       lattice_0.20-27       flashClust_1.01-2     dynamicTreeCut_1.60-1
[13] RODBC_1.3-10          ada_2.0-3             rpart_4.1-5           foreach_1.4.1
[17] stringr_0.6.2         debug_1.3.1           snow_0.3-13           ROCR_1.0-5
[21] gplots_2.12.1         rattle_3.0.2          RSNNS_0.4-4           Rcpp_0.11.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] bitops_1.0-6        caTools_1.16        cluster_1.14.4      codetools_0.2-8
[5] compiler_3.0.3      gdata_2.13.2        gtools_3.3.1        KernSmooth_2.23-10
[9] latticeExtra_0.6-26 matrixStats_0.8.14  mvbutils_2.7.4.1    R.methodsS3_1.6.1
[13] RColorBrewer_1.0-5  tools_3.0.3

Answer (score 0):

## from : http://labs.genetics.ucla.edu/horvath/CoexpressionNetwork/Rpackages/WGCNA/

install.packages(c("dynamicTreeCut", "cluster", "flashClust", "Hmisc", "reshape", "foreach", "doParallel") ) 
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R") 
biocLite("impute")

## (R) library(WGCNA)

*
*  Package WGCNA 1.34 loaded.
*
*    Important note: It appears that your system supports multi-threading,
*    but it is not enabled within WGCNA in R. 
*    To allow multi-threading within WGCNA with all available cores, use 
*
*          allowWGCNAThreads()
*
*    within R. Use disableWGCNAThreads() to disable threading if necessary.
*    Alternatively, set the following environment variable on your system:
*
*          ALLOW_WGCNA_THREADS=
*
*    for example 
*
*          ALLOW_WGCNA_THREADS=4
*
*    To set the environment variable in linux bash shell, type 
*
*           export ALLOW_WGCNA_THREADS=4
*
*     before running R. Other operating systems or shells will
*     have a similar command to achieve the same aim.

## *

Attaching package: 糎GCNA・
The following object is masked from 叢ackage:stats・

```
cor
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem I got it solved it through this

install.packages(c("matrixStats", "Hmisc", "splines", "foreach", "doParallel", "fastcluster", "dynamicTreeCut", "survival", "BiocManager"))
BiocManager::install(c("GO.db", "preprocessCore", "impute"));